# How do you split a string list to find all duplicates in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell, filter, split

Say I have a [String] of `["one", "one", "two", "three", "three", "three"]`

How would I go about splitting this [String] into a [[String]] of

`[["one", "one"], ["two"], ["three", "three", "three"]]`

Thanks for your time

Comment: see [Data.List.group](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group). perhaps you will need [`Data.List.sort`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sort) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to group consecutive values by equality as in your example input this will do

```
Prelude> Data.List.group ["one", "one", "two", "three", "three", "three"]                               
[["one","one"],["two"],["three","three","three"]]
```

otherwise, you may want to sort the list to get equal values next to each other.